# How to save data from form to table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a project in which I have to insert values from a form into a SQL Server 2008 table.

One of the value is inserted which is license number but the category column is empty in database. The code I'm using is:

```
SqlCommand qry = new SqlCommand(
"INSERT INTO licnscatagory(license_number, catagory) 
 VALUES('"+ license_numberTextBox.Text +"','"+ catagoryComboBox.Text +"')", conn;
qry.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In the database `license_number` has a datatype of `numeric` and  `category` is `varchar(50)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use This Code

```
SqlCommand qry = new SqlCommand(
     "INSERT INTO licnscatagory(license_number,catagory) 
     VALUES('"+ license_numberTextBox.Text +"','"+ catagoryComboBox.SelectedValue+"')", conn;
     qry.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is vulnerable to SQL injection hacks. Imagine a user typing the following into your license_numberTextBox.

'); DROP TABLE licnscatagory;

Aside from that, your issue is with the single quotes around what is a numeric. The proper way to do inserts such as this, or any SQL query for that matter, in ADO.NET is to use parameters. See the following:

```
        SqlCommand qry = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO licnscatagory (license_number, category) VALUES (@licenseNumber, @category)", conn);
        qry.Parameters.AddWithValue("licenseNumber", Convert.ToDecimal(license_numberTextBox.Text));
        qry.Parameters.AddWithValue("category", catagoryComboBox.Text);
        qry.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: The specific type of ComboBox control being used will dictate whether the Text property is the correct one to use to retrieve the currently selected value.

Comment: i am very thankfull to your reply.but there is a syntax problem on run time.how to fix that.the msg is "uncorrect syntax near @catagory"plz help

Comment: I have modified my reply. I missed a closing parenthesis at the end of the statement.

Comment: i am very sory to say that the new coding do same as my one that donot save the category value.i will so much thank full plz recheck that.thanks

Comment: Ad code mentioned in his answer, when using the standard WinForm ComboBox control, you will need to access the SelectedItem property from the ComboBox.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code..

```
 SqlCommand qry = new SqlCommand(
 "INSERT INTO licnscatagory(license_number,catagory) 
 VALUES('"+ license_numberTextBox.Text +"','"+ catagoryComboBox.SelectedItem.Text +"')", conn;
 qry.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: it also not working.any one can tell me that how to use "insert" method for these values